# manipulate vue.js data parameter from within sub method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I know that I can change the value of a vue data value from within a method by using `this.variable_name`. But when I'm trying to do this from within a method with a sub-method (because I'm making an ajax request) I am getting an `undefined` error.

I have something like

```
var myvue = new Vue({
    name: "MyVue",
    el: '#my-vue-id',
    data: {
        fields: field_list // this is set in another js method elsewhere
    },
    methods: {
        reject: function (index, objectid) {
            if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                $.get("/reject/" + objectid, function (data) {
                    if (data.success == true) {
                        $("#" + objectid).fadeOut(400, function() {
                            this.field_list.splice(index, 1);
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert('Failed to delete.');
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }
});
```

I also tried setting `var self = this;` within the `$.get` method, then trying to splice `self.field_list` but in both cases I get an error `Cannot read property splice of undefined`

EDIT since I may have been unclear-- the `field_list` is being populated. If I were to do `this.field_list.splice` outside the ajax function, it works fine. The issue is just how to access external scope from with the vue methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A callback function does not get your Vue instance as its context (`this`) when it is called. Use arrow functions for your callbacks, or save `this` to a variable and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the `var self = this;` outside of the `$.get` method (before it) as within the `$.get` method you have a different scope, and that is the root of the problem. Then within the `$.get` method use `self.field_list.splice(index, 1);`